# Chrome Extension: Display Sandbox Page in SidePanel And Send/Receive Messages?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, sandbox

## Question:

Has anyone figured out how to display a sandboxed page in the Chrome side panel *and send/receive messages from/to it*? Communication with sandboxed pages can only be done with `window.postMessage()`, and I don't know how to get the sidePanel's window.

### Details

- I can easily set a sandboxed page to display in the side panel
- I can't figure out how to send/receive messages to/from it

The [sandbox "page" examples chrome provides](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/api-samples/sandbox) only show how to insert an `<iframe/>`. The `<iframe/>` is not displayed and only returns a string; I want mine to display.

- Communication is done via `window.postMessage`, but I don't know how to get hold of the side panel's window.

Is it the same window as the tab that it's displayed in?

### Janky, Crummy Implementation

Following the examples as close as I can, I created a `sidePanel.html` page that contains an `<iframe/>` with the `src` set to my `sandbox.html` file. I've set the height and width to 100%, and it works: the iFrame takes up the whole side panel and renders just fine. Now, I could set up a communication interchange between the `sidePanel.html` and the `<iframe/>` by grabbing the `<iframe/>`'s currentWindow and sending the message like so:

```
... document.getElementById('theFrame').contentWindow.postMessage(message, '*');
```

and receiving it in the sandboxed page with:

```
// Set up message event handler:
      window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        const command = event.data.command;

... 

event.source.postMessage({ result: result }, event.origin);
```

But this isn't ideal and makes me think that I'm doing something wrong.

Is this *really* the way sandbox pages that send/receive messages work in a side panel? Put it in an `<iframe/>` just because I can't get access to the `<iframe>`'s window object?

Comment: The sidepanel html shouldn't be declared in `sandbox` and it should create an iframe pointing to html that is declared in `sandbox`, then you'll have a parent-iframe communication. There's no other way because the browser allows the side panel's origin to be the extension proper whereas in a sandboxed page it's null.

Comment: Okay. Based on your reply, the way I described doing is the way it should be done, Oof. My real goal here is to get around having to wait for Chrome Extension Reviwes when I make updates to my chrome extension. If we need to change the styling, or whatever, of the extension, we don't want to have to wait weeks for a review to go through and approve it.

Given my real goal, is there another way to do it?

Comment: You can display a site that you own in the iframe scaled to the entire side panel. The site can use `location.ancestorOrigins` to ensure it's embedded correctly and parent.postMessage for communication.